# Qt TCP socket - Write more that 15bytes

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

i have a problem with qt sockets...

I just created a TCP socket and i want to write a message on the server.
All works fine but when i try to write a message that have more than 15 characters it's send's random thing ...

Here is how i create my socket : `socket = new QTcpSocket(this);`

and here where i use it :

```
bool MainWindow::loginAction(QString usernameNow, QString passwordNow) {
    QString logingRequestTmp = "LOGIN " + usernameNow + " " + passwordNow;
    const char* loginRequest= logingRequestTmp.toStdString().c_str();
    socket->write(loginRequest);
    return true;
}
```

So is there a simple way to say at `socket->write()` that i want to write more than 15bytes .?

Exemple :

with username = test and password = test

-> Server receive "LOGIN test test" (15 characters) works well !

But with with username = test1 and password = test

-> Server receive "���" (16 characters) not working well ...

Ps : When i try `socket->write("123456789123456789")` it works ... only don't work when i pass to `socket->write()` a `const char*` already created with 15+ characters

Comment: I tried QIODevice::write(data, qstrlen(data)); like in the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write

Comment: but don't work : socket->write(loginRequest, qstrlen(loginRequest));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String to byte conversion is no longer just "assume everything is 7-bit ASCII".  It's better to be explicit about encoding, and the byproduct is that you get to stay in Qt land.  Ditch the `std::string()` conversion.

I'd use the socket->write() overload that takes a `QByteArray`, which you can get from the original `QString`:

```
socket->write(logingRequestTmp.toUtf8());
```

or if you're not doing Utf, then any of the other QString functions that return QByteArrays work too: `toLatin1()`, for example.

Comment: Thx you so mutch @Peter ! Working for me !!